# MSYS2 can't find targeted directories

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, msys

I am building FFMPEG on windows. I installed MSYS2 and all the rest of the tools and libs I need for that task. As long as I don't need to configure external libraries,like h264, all is good. But in the case of h264, I have to speicify include and library location. And no matter what I try I always end up with

> ERROR:libx264 not found

Here is how I defines those paths in MSYS:

```
--extra-cflags="-I./x264" --extra-ldflags="-L./x264/lib" --extra-libs=-ldl
```

Now,to ease my pains I put the lib folder named "x264" in the same directory where MSYS terminal is currently working,in a directory above,and also in the root directory of drive "d".And I tried also these variations:

```
 --extra-cflags="-I/d/x264" --extra-ldflags="-L/d/x264/lib" --extra-libs=-ldl

 --extra-cflags="-I/../x264" --extra-ldflags="-L/../x264/lib" --extra-libs=-ldl
```

Still getting

> ERROR:libx264 not found

What is wrong in this setup?

Comment: The Windows drive letter has no relevance here. See the contents of etc/fstab in the msys2 dir. You can add a path there, or reference a path inside one of those specified. In case x264's .pc file is not located by ffmpeg, you should add `-lx264` as well.

Comment: I understood nothing of what you said.

Comment: See the contents of etc/fstab in the msys2 dir. You'll see a list of Windows paths on the left side of each line and unix-style paths on the right. Your path specifications in cflags and ldflags have to be unix-style. So, your x264 pathspec has to be specified in terms of the right-side paths. e.g. if a line says `d:\xyz /xyz`, then you can place x264 folder inside xyz and reference it as `/xyz/x264/lib`. If ffmpeg doesn't find x264's pkg-config file, then it will fail unless `-lx264` is added.

Comment: That's what I have in the etc/stab: none / cygdrive binary,posix=0,noacl,user 0 0

Comment: But now I see that in my x264.pc file the paths are wrong.

Comment: Leave a line after that and add `d:\windows\path\to\x264 /x264`. Adjust the .pc file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68473/discussion-between-michael-iv-and-mulvya).

Comment: That doesn't work. Now the lib path points to it points to a '/LC:/msys64/x264/lib/'